# Calculating difference between consecutive rows, then finding top 3 IDs with highest count of negative differences SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having a lot of difficulty writing an SQL query. I need to compute the difference between consecutive rows for 4 different regions across different years, then subsequently display only the top 3 regions with the highest count of negative differences. An example as shown below:

| Region | Year | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| central | 01 | null |
| central | 02 | 10 |
| central | 03 | -9 |
| east | 01 | -29 |
| east | 02 | 10 |
| east | 03 | -9 | central | -29 |
| west | 02 | 10 |
| west | 03 | -9 | central | -29 |
| west | 02 | 10 |
| north | 03 | -9 | central | -29 |
| north | 02 | 10 |
| north | 03 | -9 |

What I currently did to find the difference was to utilise the lag function in sql.

The current problems I'm facing are:

- The first year for each region should all have null differences, since there is no year before the first year. However, only my first row in the select statement has a null value, the rest of the first years for the other regions have a non-null as there is a value before it (the latest year in the previous region comes before it).
- After obtaining all the differences, how do I only show the top 3 regions that have the most instances of negative differences?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm racking my brain at this query. Thank you!

Comment: just an edit: managed to solve the qn of null value by partitioning by region. still unsure of the second part

Comment: do you need a sum of every row with the one before it or a running total? also, that's that central thing to the side?

Comment: you've done something wrong with the difference col. Can you share the table you had?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  The simple answers need 8.0 or 10.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert null values in Differnce into something, for ex. 0 if 0 means a neutral value because there is no information.

```
SELECT Region
, SUM(CASE WHEN IFNULL(Difference,0) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CountDifference
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY CountDifference DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Also here: https://dbfiddle.uk/83qE9RX2

Comment: What happens if there's a tie? even with this data you're not presenting `south` even though it has the same number of negatives as `north`.

Comment: He didnt provide additional information for a tie, he just wanted a limit of 3! You can comment on his question. Also its a data sample and for a sample you dont need all the data.

Comment: eliminating data without any logic behind it is not a good move in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah its not but i was his recruitment.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it after some thinking with a nested select

```
select region, count(*) 
from ("nested statement here") f
where difference < 0
group by region
order by count(*) desc
limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First we fix the difference column by making every first year value `null`. `Then we group by region` and `count` all the case where `difference < 0`. After that we use `dense_rank()` to find all the regions with the top count results (including ties).

```
select   Region
        ,negative_differece_count
from     (
         select   *
                  ,dense_rank() over(order by negative_differece_count desc) as dns_rnk
         from     (  
                  select   Region
                          ,count(case when (case when Year = 1 then null else Difference end) < 0 then 1 end) as negative_differece_count
                  from     t
                  group by Region
                  ) t
         ) t
where    dns_rnk <= 3
```

| Region | negative_differece_count |
| --- | --- |
| north | 2 |
| central | 1 |
| east | 1 |
| west | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jaywUPBg)